# Вход в каталог- в чем разница?

Tags: linux, shell

Какая разница между командой

```
cd films
```

и

```
cd films/
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это не «вход в каталог», а внутренняя команда оболочки для смены текущего каталога у процесса оболочки (текущий каталог — это одно из свойств процесса).

разница же — лишь в том, что в одном варианте команды есть слэш, а в другом — нет. всё.

Answer (score 0):

Никакой.
cd поймёт вас и так и так.
А, вот, для остального (Текстовые редакторы vi/nano/e.t.c.) будет большая разница.
Если, скажем, у вас будет файл films и директория films, то при наборе `vi films/` вы получите сообщение от vi

> "/path/to/dir/films is a directory"

Comment: *Если, скажем, у вас будет файл films и директория films* — а вы пробовали воспроизвести такую ситуацию? насколько мне известно, она просто невозможна. ну, по крайней мере без прямого редактирования т.н. «каталожного файла» (ведь с технической точки зрения каталог — это тоже файл, но «специальный»).

Comment: Александр, вы правы, просто вылетело из головы. Ни в win ни в nix сделать такое не выйдет.